# Usage of "vorher" and "vorhin"

Tags: difference, usage

What is the difference between *vorhin* and *vorher*? Both mean *ago* in my dictionary. When are they used and in what context?

> 1. Ich habe mit dir vorher gesprochen.
> 2. Ich habe mit dir vorhin gesprochen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Vorher** refers to the time before a certain event like **before** or **prior**.

**Vorhin** is used to point to a single point in time like **earlier**.

1. I have spoken to you before we ...
2. I have talked to you earlier.

Referring to your examples:

1. You talked to me before something happened.
2. You talked to me earlier.

Answer (score 7):

The other answer contains some mistakes that set you up for wrong use of the words.

*Vorhin*

Refers to an earlier point in time of the same day as in the day you use the word. It usually spans back between 2 and 4 hours from "now".

> Dein Chef hat vorhin angerufen.

A translation is *earlier* but keep in mind that *vorhin* works like *now* and always means the current day.

> vorhin = now - 2 to 4 hours

*vorher*

Points at an event in time that has been established in speech and sets another event before that. It is synonymous with *davor (before that)* in the temporal domain.

> Ich esse. Vorher koche ich.

More can be found on my [blog](http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/gerade-eben-fruher-vorhin-eben/).

Comment: Hrrrm .... das mit dem "selben Tag" steht wo? Das würde bedeuten, man könnte 5 Minuten nach 12 nicht sagen: Bring mal den Sekt, den ich vorhin (nämlich gestern, 23:50) aufgemacht habe? Im übrigen wurde "vorhin" früher auch im Sinne von "in früheren Zeiten" gebraucht.

Comment: @Ingo ich meine den "menschlichen" selben Tag... also von aufwachen bis schlafen. Und ja ein Nickerchen von 23-1 Uhr funktioniert auch noch. Aber in einem ROman kann man es zum Beispiel nur in direkter Rede verwenden während "earlier" auch in der Erzählperspektive funktioniert.

Comment: @Ingo ... bitte gib mal ein Beispiel für deine Verwendung von "vorhin" als "in früherer Zeit".

Comment: Zum Beispiel in "Königlich-Baierisches Regierungsblatt" von 1806 - zu finden bei books.google.com mit Suchbegriff "vorhin", letzter Eintrag auf der ersten Suchergebnis-Seite. Im Buch Seite 469. Probe: "Die Pfarrey Neukirchen am Inn, im Landgerichte Passau gelegen, und **vorhin** zum Kloster barnbach gehörig ..." hier wird also "vorhin" wie "vormals" oder "bisher" verwendet.

Comment: @Ingo ok... aber das ist über 200 Jahre her. Damals hat man vieles gesagt, was heute nicht mehr gesagt wird, also bitte ein Beispiel aus der Gegenwart :)

Comment: Es war nicht meine Behauptung, daß es heutzutage noch so gebraucht wird, somit muß ich dafür keine Belege bringen. Ich dachte nur, der Hinweis könnte wichtig sein für den Deutsch Lernenden, möglicherweise liest er ja mal was aus dem 19. Jahrhundert.

Comment: ops... ich hab' das erste "früher" nicht gesehen... sorry!

Comment: When a reference point in time was not explicitly previously set, I can still use "vorher"? In this case, I'd assume that the implicit reference point in time is "now". eg. Ich hatte sie vorher noch nie gesehen (Duden example in "vorher" definition)